# How to connect to firestore from my local machine?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I'm trying to connect to firestore by using the [quickstart guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart), I'm using **Initialize on your own server** part.

Here's my quick sample code

```
import admin, { ServiceAccount } from 'firebase-admin';

import serviceAccount from '../../serviceAccount.json';

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount as ServiceAccount)
});

const db = admin.firestore();
const aTuringRef = db.collection('users').doc('aturing');

aTuringRef
  .set({
    first: 'Alan',
    middle: 'Mathison',
    last: 'Turing',
    born: 1912,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('done');
  });
```

My code never prints `done` and I get this error:

```
(node:95103) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Total timeout of API google.firestore.v1.Firestore exceeded 600000 milliseconds before any response was received.
```

I'm not really sure what to do in order to troubleshoot this issue, I've used firestore before in firebase functions but I've never used it in a custom NodeJS server.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that your local machine has some kind of Firewall or network restriction that would prevent it from performing requests to the Firestore API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was being stupid, but I'll post the answer if anyone has this issue in the future.

I had `FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST` set in my .bash_profile, therefore `firebase-admin` was trying to connect against the emulator.

When I had this variable `unset` my `firebase-admin` started to communicate against production firestore.